# Minted cannot find pygmentize in TexStudio on Windows 7

Tags: windows, python

I want to use minted package, but when I'm `xelatexing` in `TexStudio`, there's an error:

```
minted: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

`pip` seems unable to find pygmentize:

[image]

In my `C:\Python26\Scripts` there are files named `pygmentize`:

[image]

I have followed instructions from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/how-to-use-minted-under-miktex-and-windows-7 where it is suggested to install Pygments which is what I did:

[image]

This is my PATH:

```
C:\Users\Milos\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Python26;C:\Python26\Scripts
```

However it is not working. How should I fix this?

Comment: I have a feeling this is probably off-topic: if the Python set up you have doesn't work in this regard then that's not really a TeX problem!

Comment: I will check my Win7 rig about this, but can't until tomorrow.

Comment: I would appreciate that. :)
Well, if not here, where could I post the question then? :)

Comment: I guess SuperUser might be the best place: probably if we migrate you'll want to edit it down to drop the TeX angle (which isn't really crucial here).

Comment: Thanks. :) How can the question be migrated? Should I delete this one and post another on SuperUser or there's a way to do it automatically somehow? :)

Comment: I can migrate if that is OK with you

Comment: I'm fine with that. :)

Comment: Did you try closing/reopening TeXStudio? Can you compile from the command line (`xelatex filename`)?

Comment: I did closing/reopening TexStudio and it works. Thanks. I feel so silly now. :)

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same problem, but on Windows 10. I will now write a proper answer for future users.

There are 3 things that must be done in order to use the minted package in TeX:

1. Change your pdflatex output to include -shell-escape,
2. Make sure pygmentize is installed in your python shell, and most difficultly
3. Make sure TeX prioritizes the correct PATH.

Solutions:

1. Go to Options in your preferred TeX editor and change the PdfLaTeX
   to: whatever it was before and then "-shell-escape %.tex"
2. Go to your Python Shell, fx Anaconda Prompt if you're using Anaconda
   as your Python editor. Check if pygmentize is already installed by
   writing: `pygmentize -V`. If it brings up your current version,
   continue to solution 3. If not, type: `pip install Pygments`. This
   should install pygmentize in whatever folder your Python editor uses
   for scripts, which is needed for the next solution.
3. First, use Windows search to find "pygmentize.exe". Copy the path
   from the address bar, fx
   "C:\Users\YourUsernameHere\Anaconda3\Scripts".

   Now use Windows search to find "Advanced System Settings". Clicking
   on the result should bring you exactly to the "Advanced" tab of the
   System Settings, if not, go there. There will be a button for
   "Environment Variables...", click on it.

   Under the "User variables for YourUsernameHere", click on the
   variable "Path" and then click "Edit...". Create a new path for the
   copied path from earlier, fx
   "C:\Users\YourUsernameHere\Anaconda3\Scripts", and then click "Move
   up" until it is above any TeX related paths.

   Restart your computer. Minted should now work :)

Hope this helps someone in the future save precious time that I wasted myself. Net gain!

Comment: I installed Python via Windows App store, and this is the location where I found my `pygmentize.exe`: 

`c:\users\myusername\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\Scripts\pygmentize.exe`

I hope this helps someone find this quicker than I did.

Answer (score 1):

- You need only to install `Pygments` into Python, `Pygmentize` is a command available once `Pygments` have been installed.

  You can check it has been properly installed on Windows and can be accessed in the PATH by typing in a command line:

  > pygmentize -h

  Which will print the help message.
- Don't forget to use the `-shell-escape` option in order to allow your tex compiler to access the external commands.

  See how to do it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx)
- Make sure you have all your MiKTeX packages up to date.
  In my case, my antivirus software was preventing some MiKTeX packages updates, which in turn where making minted unusable.

  I fount this solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82054/problems-installing-miktex)
- As @darthbith suggested in the comments, closing and reopening (or a system restart) can be needed for the PATH to be reloaded.